# Linux RAID using intel motherboard

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

Having an issue with installing Linux on my raid array. I have created and configured the raid5 (6x500GB) array using the Intel bios option. When proceeding to the install Ubuntu on the array it shows up as one 2.5TB drive, which is what I am used to seeing. However, after the install it keeps dropping me into a initramfs prompt. I have tried creating my own partitions as well and I get the same issue. I feel like I am missing something, this usually worked just fine in the past...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain, but depending on what motherboard you have, the MD driver in Linux may be trying to assemble the array itself, and as a result screwing with the configuration done by the firmware (If it's integrated on a MB, it's almost never hardware RAID, and is usually done in firmware).  Also, if it's a newer Intel motherboard, then the storage controller's 'RAID' mode isn't supported under Linux (that mode mostly exists to allow Windows to have easy to configure RAID, and also to bypass Microsoft's poor power management configuration in their AHCI driver).

All that aside, as a general rule, you almost certainly want to use software RAID and not firmware RAID when dealing with anything but Windows.  The issue you're seeing is one reason for this, but other big ones are:

- If you have to replace the motherboard, you may lose the RAID configuration (either because the firmware stores it in NVRAM, or because the new MB doesn't support the same RAID implementation).
- With software RAID (at least, when using LVM which is the preferred method in Ubuntu I believe), you can more easily handle device failures online, and also have better control of how they're handled.

Comment: Guess I'm learning software RAID in Linux then haha. Weird thing is that it worked fine before I reinstalled Linux on the same hardware. But your points are well taken and I'll just move to software RAID.

Comment: For what it's worth, LVM actually has really good documentation, so learning to use it is pretty easy if you already understand the basics of working with block devices.

Comment: Figured that I could follow the documentation this documentation, seems pretty straight forward. One question I do have is supposing I have 16GB of RAM. Do I really need 32GB of swap space on each drive?
 or just 32 GB spaced over all the drives total?
 https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html

Comment: you don't really need 32GB of swap on a 16GB system.  You certainly don't need 6x32GB of swap.   Having some swap space is useful, but 2xRAM just isn't necessary except, perhaps, on machines with very small 1990s-era RAM sizes.   I'd suggest between 1 and 4GB of swap on each drive - don't bother with raid for swap, just create individual swap partitions on each drive and Linux will spread the swap usage over all of them.

Comment: If you care about high availability though, putting the swap space on RAID is good for that, but you probably want RAID10 for that, not 5 or 6.

Comment: Also, unless you expect to be using swap space regularly (you probably won't be unless you're actively overcommitting RAM), you may be better off using a compressed ramdisk for swap (search 'zram swap' followed by whatever your distro is for info on how to do this).